# Getting error 502 instead of displaying errors on nginx + php-fpm

Tags: nginx, php

I've tried everything and i can't still get to display errors on the browser, I'm using nginx, php-fpm and centOS 6.4

nginx.conf

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

this is my nginx config inside conf.d

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  localhost;
root /server/public;
index run.php;


location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /run.php;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_index   run.php;
    fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
    include         fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

php-fpm config

```
catch_workers_output = yes
php_flag[display_errors] = on
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
```

php.ini

```
display_errors = on
log_errors = on
```

I'm running CentOS 6.4 on virtualbox with NAT enabled, if i curl localhost from inside the server i get the correct error but if i access the site from the browser outside of the server i get a 502 bad gateway error, if the page I'm loading has no errors everything works fine, am I missing anything?

Comment: `cat` your `/var/log/nginx/error.log` file and figure out the exact error that the webserver is seeing when you access the system, since a 502 usually means the gateway is not configured right, and with `php5-fpm` it usually means you're not `fastcgi_pass`-ing to the right path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wondering why you were getting that error I could give you few hints.

error 502 means bad gateway, means that the php server that nginx was trying to proxy to wasn't responding, maybe because php5-fpm wasn't listening to port 9000 and it was using a sock file instead, or could be that php wasn't running at all(if all php files aren't working)

Why did you get different responses from curl and the browser?, well because your server is defined as `localhost` I'm assuming both methods were not being captured by different server blocks.

The correct method to have fixed this is to check the active virtual hosts, and the php5-fpm listen config,

I think it's just coincidence that install the new php fixed the issue probably because it overwritten the old config file to a new one that worked with the nginx config.

But anyway, I was just trying to give you some hints of what to check if you ever find a similar problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was my version of php (5.3) that was failing, after updating to php 5.5 it started working